# Is all algebraic system is monoid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algebraic-groups, semigroups, monoid

Is all Algebraic system is monoid?
I cross-checked the properties of both monoid and algebraic systems. Here is what I found:

*Properties of Algebraic system:
1.closure property
2.Associativity
3.commutativity
4.existence of identity
5.Existence of inverse*

*Property of monoid
1.Associativity
2.existence of identity element.*

Considering above mentioned properties I think **all Algebraic systems are monoid**.
But the problem is,
Questions are asked "Given an algebraic system... Check whether it's a monoid? or show that it's a monoid. Please clear my doubt!
**Edit**
To be clear about algebraic system and algebraic structures ,here is what I found:

An *algebraic system* is a system consisting of a nonempty set A and one or more n-ary operations on the set A. It is denoted by ⟨A,f1,f2,...⟩.
An *algebraic structure* is an algebraic system, ⟨A,f1,f2,...,R1,R2,...⟩, wherein addition to operations fi, the relations Ri are defined on A. This leads to a structure on the elements of A.
*Note: My doubt is about Algebraic system (not algebraic structure) and monoids!*

Comment: What is an algebraic system? There are algebraic structures which don't contain an identity, e.g. semigroups.

Comment: Can you explain difference between algebraic system and algebraic structure. I didn't get 

Comment: I supposed that there might be a difference, if not, then consider a semi-group, which do not contain an identity, hence they aren't monoid.

Comment: But the conditions of a monoid is satisfied in Algebraic system, according to the  properties I have stated above

Comment: Okay to be clear, if we consider your definition of  an algebraic system then this is correct. However, the usual definition is different (I only know the term "algebraic structure" that's why I have asked if there is a difference). In the usual sense an algebraic structure is much weaker. Shaun mentioned an example. A Magma is an algebraic structure in the usual sense as well as a semigroup is. Both aren't monoid.

Comment: Ok,now I got my mistake. Those properties were properties of binary operation. So we have to check the conditions in set given in algebraic system. Then only we can say  whether an algebraic system  is monoid or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Consider a magma $(M,\ast)$, which is simply a set $M$ with a binary operation $\ast:M\times M\to M$. It needn't be associative.